# Devise not displaying login error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise on my application and i am not getting error messages when login fails.

I've flash[:notice] and flash[:alert] on the login page.

I tried a lot of things and when i remove 'protect_from_forgery' from application controller i get the error messages.

Also i am using Cancan on my application, can it be any issue from it? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the authenticity verification is failing. Are your forms sending up the authenticity_token with posts? If removing `protect_from_forgery` fixes it, this almost certainly the problem.

Make sure that all non-get requests are sending up an `authenticity_token` parameter with the value returned by the rails function `form_authenticity_token`. If you use `form_for` in your views, this should happen automagically. Check your html to be sure, the authenticity token in the form should match the value returned the `form_authenticity_token` method.

Comment: Good answer @drewbob.  I had this problem just yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, a bit hacky, but I'm using this helper (app/helpers/devise_helper.rb) to grab flashes and use those if set then default to `resource.errors`. Devise's sessions controller doesn't seem to use the model errors, but uses flash alerts instead. This is just based on the helper that's in the devise lib.

```
module DeviseHelper

  def devise_error_messages!
    flash_alerts = []
    error_key = 'errors.messages.not_saved'

    if !flash.empty?
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:error]) if flash[:error]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:alert]) if flash[:alert]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
      error_key = 'devise.failure.invalid'
    end

    return "" if resource.errors.empty? && flash_alerts.empty?
    errors = resource.errors.empty? ? flash_alerts : resource.errors.full_messages

    messages = errors.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t(error_key, :count    => errors.count,
                                 :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end

end
```